# Why does emotional pain sometimes feels like physical pain?

Tags: psychology, brain, pain

So here's a question from a newbie. I read somewhere that emotional pain can last as long as 20 minutes. Anything painful you feel beyond that is just a result of overthinking.

Well whatever it is, why does it effect our overall being so much? We feel that actual clenching pain in our heart like it will stop beating any minute. The pain is that strong. Our sleep and eating patterns get disturbed.

Why? It's just an emotion. Why can't our bodies seem to differentiate between emotional pain and physical hurt?